# Internet working selectively on some devices

Tags: internet, home-networking, internet-connection

I have a HP pavilion p028tx with windows 10 and a tp-link modem. The wifi i am using is getting connected in the laptop but with a limited sign and no internet access is available. I can connect other networks on the laptop and other devices (smartphones) can connect to the wifi where it is working.

When, some rare times it does work om the laptop, hovering over the network button in the bottom right balloons up this message "{WiFi name} 2" while in the non-working spells, it is "{WiFi name} 3", where the numbers differ. I am also unable to reach the modem via the laptop (192.168.0.1) and the problem persists even if i use an ethernet cable. Accessing the modem via a working net on smartphone works.

I tried the usual diagnostics, troubleshooting, and also used cmd to purge the dns cache, and used the netsh winsock reset, nbtstat -R and nbtstat -RR commands but to no avail. Rebooting the modem, laptop, and everything also didn't work.

Apologise in advance if it is not on-topic in here, but a fix is urgently needed. Am unsure of the tags too. Do let me know if more info is required.